# Do "live" and "stay" require prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

Do the following sentences work with or without the prepositions?

This is a good place to stay (at).

This is a good place to live (in).

Comment: This question is almost exactly the same as http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/97810/good-place-to-go-to-live - see if that one answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the prepositions would only be required when dealing with a specific noun.

For example: This is a good **HOUSE** to stay (in/at(in sounds more natural to me))

Or: This is a good **HOUSE** to live in.

Your two sentences are proper, no prepositions required.

Answer (score 1):

They work both with and without the prepositions.

You'll find many articles with a search of "end sentence with preposition" on how teachers used to say this was wrong, but that the "old rule" of never ending a sentence with a preposition is a Latin grammar concept attempted to be forced into English's Germanic grammar roots, and therefore it's not really a big deal.

It helps clarify things as well.  For example, *This is a good place to live* - we're not sure if you mean the neighboorhood, country, house, or what type of place, but by saying *This is a good place to live in*, it's clearer you probably mean a house or at least something with a roof.

Comment: A city, for instance, is a place to live in aswell. However, it is much less common.

Comment: @LawrenceC Quibbling here, slightly, but you might be able to come up with a better example than _This is a good place to live in_. A localism, maybe, but I often hear _Lower Rat Rapids is a good place to live in_ and similiar.